# Multiple websites using the same app - how to set this up?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have an app that shows products available in the US. If i want to change the country, I simply modify the value of a variable in my settings.py file.

Now... each country I serve needs to have its own site, e.g. example.co.uk, example.ca, etc. They'll all be hosted on the same server and use the same database. The views, static files,etc. would be almost the same for each country.

What's the best way of setting this up? Should I have one main app and then have per-country apps that extend the app?

(Using Django 1.6.2/Python 2.7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had something similar to do.

I have for each domain a specific setting file with an unique `SITE_ID` and also a wsgi file per site. Then in my http.conf (I'm using apache on webfaction) i set up multiple `VirtualHost` instances, each pointing out to the specific wsgi file.

My configuration looks something like this:

- random_django_app/

  - `__init__.py`
  - models.py
  - ...
- another_app/

  - ...
- settings_app/

  - settings/

    - `__init__.py`
    - base.py
    - example_co_uk.py
    - example_ca.py
    - ...
  - wsgis/

    - `__init__.py`
    - example_co_uk.py
    - example_ca.py
  - `__init__.py`
  - urls.py

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try [django-dynamicsites](https://bitbucket.org/uysrc/django-dynamicsites), not sure how well it will work with 1.6.2, I've used it on a project a few versions back. It worked great, you could override settings, urls and templates for each site and share everything else.
There is another project called [django-dynamicsites-lite](https://github.com/wardi/django-dynamicsites-lite) that looks a bit more recent.